# How to save memory using half precision while keeping the original weights in single?

Tags: memory-management, pytorch, neural-network, cuda, automatic-mixed-precision

I'm trying to save memory while training a model that uses single precision weights by doing the calculations in half precision.

I tried using autocast, and the model does prediction in half precision as it should.
However the gradient produced is still in single precision.
This ruins both performance and memory savings.
Is there any way to instruct torch to calculate grads in half precision and use those to update the original single precision weights?

```
import torch

class KekNet (torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(KekNet, self).__init__()
        self.layer1 = torch.nn.Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), dtype=torch.float32)
    
    def forward(self, x, features=False):
        return self.layer1(x)

device = torch.device("cuda")


# HALF-DATA AUTOCAST

net = KekNet().to(device)

loss_l2  = torch.nn.MSELoss(reduction='none')
g_params = [{'params': net.parameters(), 'weight_decay': 0}]
optimizerG = torch.optim.RMSprop(g_params, lr=3e-5, alpha=0.99, eps=1e-07, weight_decay=0)
schedulerG = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.CosineAnnealingLR(optimizerG, T_max=300)

X = torch.randn((40,3,555,555), dtype=torch.float16, device =device)

with torch.autocast(device_type='cuda', dtype=torch.float16):
    Y_h=net(X)

Y = torch.randn_like(Y_h)
loss = loss_l2(Y_h, Y).mean()

loss.backward()

print(f"-autocast\r\ndata precision: {X.dtype}\r\npred precision: {Y_h.dtype}\r\ngrad precision: {net.layer1.weight.grad.dtype}\r\n")

optimizerG.step()
schedulerG.step()
```

results in following:

```
data precision: torch.float16
pred precision: torch.float16
grad precision: torch.float32
```

Comment: Your question is about PyTorch, not CUDA programming. Please refrain from adding the CUDA tag

Comment: The mixed precision op is performed by CUDA, not torch, so the cuda tag stays.

Answer (score 1):

Autocast doesn't transform the weights of the model, so weight grads will have the same dtype as the weights. You can try manually calling `.half()` on the model to change this. I'm not sure if there's a way to compute grads in fp16 while keeping the weights in fp32.

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

torch.set_default_device('cuda')

model = nn.Linear(8,1)
opt = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=1e-3)

x = torch.randn(12, 8, dtype=torch.float16)

with torch.autocast(device_type='cuda', dtype=torch.float16, enabled=True):
    output = model(x)
    loss = output.mean()
loss.backward()
    
print(model.weight.grad.dtype)
# > torch.float32

opt.zero_grad()

model.half()

with torch.autocast(device_type='cuda', dtype=torch.float16, enabled=True):
    output = model(x)
    loss = output.mean()
loss.backward()
    
print(model.weight.grad.dtype)
# > torch.float16
```

Additionally, some ops have numerical stability issues when computed in fp16. To avoid this, pytorch autocasts certain opts to fp32. You can find the full list [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/amp.html#cuda-ops-that-can-autocast-to-float32).

In your case, MSE loss (and really the `pow` function) autocast to fp32. This won't change the weight grad dtype in the example above, but worth noting if you see fp32 cropping up other places.

Comment: From what I understand cuda allows mixed precision ops, so if I had a 16 bit gradient I should be able theoretically to use it to update the weights in 32 bit. So I tried to change the gradient precision to half instead, after running `backward()`, but torch won't allow me.

Comment: Another thought is, perhaps we can store the model weights in two chunks of half precision somehow that when combined give you single precision. We would then use one chunk for the optimizer, update the parameters then recombine and split again. Is this possible?