Is it necessary for torch_dtype when loading a model and the precision for trainable weights to be different? If so, why?
According to this comment in the huggingface/peft package, if a model is loaded in fp16, the trainable weights must be cast to fp32. From this comment, I understand that generally, the torch_dtype used when loading a model and the precision used for training must be different. Why is it necessary to change the precision? Also, does this principle apply to both fine-tuning and continual pretraining?
As a minimal working example, I'm attempting to perform a continual pretraining on microsoft/Phi-3-mini-128k-instruct, whose default torch_dtype is bfloat16. When loading the model with torch_dtype=torch.float16, training commenced when the precision for trainable weights was set to TrainingArguments(fp16=False, bf16=True) (i.e. different precision for model loading and trainable weights). However, when the precision for trainable weights was set to TrainingArguments(fp16=True, bf16=False) (i.e. same precision for model loading and trainable weights), an error raise ValueError("Attempting to unscale FP16 gradients.") occurred, preventing the start of training. The execution environment was an NVIDIA RTX3060 with only 12GB of vRAM. For continual pretraining of the Phi-3 model, how should the torch_dtype be set when loading the model and for trainable weights to minimize vRAM usage? For instance, should the model be loaded with torch_dtype=fp32 and the precision for trainable weights set to TrainingArguments(fp16=True, bf16=False), or should the model be loaded with load_in_8bit and the precision for trainable weights set to TrainingArguments(fp16=True, bf16=False)? I would like to know effective and feasible combinations.
MWE
train_deepspeed.py
import argparse
import os
import warnings
from typing import Dict, List
import deepspeed
import torch
from datasets import load_dataset
from omegaconf import OmegaConf
from transformers import (
    AutoModelForCausalLM,
    AutoTokenizer,
    PreTrainedTokenizer,
    Trainer,
    TrainingArguments,
)
import gc
from utils import seed_everything

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

os.environ["TOKENIZERS_PARALLELISM"] = "false"

def preprocess_function(
    examples: Dict[str, List[str]],
    tokenizer: PreTrainedTokenizer,
    max_length: int,
) -> Dict[str, List[int]]:
    inputs = tokenizer(
        examples["text"],
        truncation=True,
        padding="max_length",
        max_length=max_length,
    )
    inputs["labels"] = inputs.input_ids.copy()
    return inputs


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        "--train_config",
        "-p",
        type=str,
        default="./configs/train_configs/train_base.yaml",
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "--local_rank",
        "-l",
        type=int,
        default=0,
    )
    args = parser.parse_args()

    config = OmegaConf.load(args.train_config)

    # distributed learning
    deepspeed.init_distributed()

    # set seed
    seed_everything(config.seed)

    # load model
    model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
        config.model.model,
        torch_dtype=torch.float16,
        use_cache=config.model.use_cache,
        device_map={"": 0},
        attn_implementation="flash_attention_2",
    )
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(
        config.model.tokenizer,
        add_eos_token=True,
    )

    # load dataset
    dataset = load_dataset(
        path=config.dataset.path,
        name=config.dataset.subset,
        split=config.dataset.split,
        cache_dir=config.dataset.cache_dir,
    )

    # transform dataset
    dataset = dataset.map(
        lambda examples: preprocess_function(
            examples, tokenizer, config.model.max_length
        ),
        batched=True,
        remove_columns=dataset.column_names,
        num_proc=32,
    )

    dataset = dataset.train_test_split(test_size=0.2)

    # initiate training
    training_args = TrainingArguments(**config.train)
    trainer = Trainer(
        model=model,
        tokenizer=tokenizer,
        train_dataset=dataset["train"],
        eval_dataset=dataset["test"],
        args=training_args,
        # data_collator=data_collator,
    )

    with torch.autocast("cuda"):
        trainer.train()

    del dataset
    del trainer

    gc.collect()
    deepspeed.runtime.utils.empty_cache()
    torch.cuda.empty_cache()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

train_base.yaml
model:
  model: microsoft/Phi-3-mini-128k-instruct
  tokenizer: microsoft/Phi-3-mini-128k-instruct
  use_cache: False
  max_length: 512


train:
  output_dir: ./outputs
  evaluation_strategy: steps
  logging_strategy: steps
  save_strategy: steps
  learning_rate: 1e-6
  num_train_epochs: 3
  per_device_train_batch_size: 1
  per_device_eval_batch_size: 1
  gradient_accumulation_steps: 256 # per_device_train_bath_size*gradient_accumulation_steps=256
  gradient_checkpointing: True
  weight_decay: 0.01
  warmup_ratio: 0.1
  optim: adamw_bnb_8bit # adamw_torch
  fp16: False
  bf16: True
  dataloader_num_workers: 1
  eval_steps: 50
  save_steps: 100
  logging_steps: 5
  run_name: test
  save_total_limit: 2
  save_on_each_node: False
  neftune_noise_alpha: 5 # NEFTTune
  # deepspeed: ./configs/deepspeed/ds_config_zero2.json
  report_to: wandb
  torch_compile: True
  logging_dir: ./outputs/log
  
seed: 42

dataset:
  path: hotchpotch/wikipedia-ja-20231030
  subset: chunked #!!null
  split: train
  cache_dir: /mnt/d/huggingface/datasets

pyproject.toml
[tool.poetry]
name = "continual-pretrain"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["Carlos Luis Rivera"]
license = "MIT"
readme = "README.md"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.11"
fsspec = "2024.3.1"
datasets = "^2.19.2"
accelerate = "^0.31.0"
aiohttp = "^3.9.5"
aiosignal = "^1.3.1"
annotated-types = "^0.7.0"
appdirs = "^1.4.4"
async-timeout = "^4.0.3"
attrs = "^23.2.0"
bitsandbytes = "^0.43.1"
certifi = "^2024.6.2"
charset-normalizer = "^3.3.2"
click = "^8.1.7"
deepspeed = "^0.14.2"
dill = "^0.3.8"
docker-pycreds = "^0.4.0"
docstring-parser = "^0.16"
filelock = "^3.14.0"
frozenlist = "^1.4.1"
gitdb = "^4.0.11"
gitpython = "^3.1.43"
hjson = "^3.1.0"
huggingface-hub = "^0.23.3"
idna = "^3.7"
jinja2 = "^3.1.4"
markdown-it-py = "^3.0.0"
markupsafe = "^2.1.5"
mdurl = "^0.1.2"
mpmath = "^1.3.0"
multidict = "^6.0.5"
multiprocess = "^0.70.16"
networkx = "^3.3"
ninja = "^1.11.1.1"
numpy = "^1.26.4"
nvidia-ml-py = "^12.555.43"
packaging = "^24.0"
pandas = "^2.2.2"
peft = "0.6.0"
protobuf = "<5.0.0"
psutil = "^5.9.8"
py-cpuinfo = "^9.0.0"
pyarrow = "^16.1.0"
pyarrow-hotfix = "^0.6"
pydantic = "^2.7.3"
pydantic-core = "^2.18.4"
pygments = "^2.18.0"
pynvml = "^11.5.0"
python-dateutil = "^2.9.0.post0"
pytz = "^2024.1"
pyyaml = "^6.0.1"
regex = "^2024.5.15"
requests = "^2.32.3"
rich = "^13.7.1"
safetensors = "^0.4.3"
scipy = "^1.13.1"
sentencepiece = "^0.2.0"
sentry-sdk = "^2.5.1"
setproctitle = "^1.3.3"
shtab = "^1.7.1"
six = "^1.16.0"
smmap = "^5.0.1"
sympy = "^1.12.1"
tokenizers = "^0.19.1"
tqdm = "^4.66.4"
transformers = "^4.41.2"
trl = "^0.9.4"
typing-extensions = "^4.12.2"
tyro = "^0.8.4"
tzdata = "^2024.1"
urllib3 = "^2.2.1"
wandb = "^0.17.1"
xxhash = "^3.4.1"
yarl = "^1.9.4"
omegaconf = "^2.3.0"
llama-cpp-python = { version = "^0.2.77", source = "llama_cpp_python_cu121" }
torch = { version = "^2.3.1+cu121", source = "torch_cu121" }
nvidia-cublas-cu12 = { version = "^12.1.3.1", source = "torch_cu121" }
nvidia-cuda-cupti-cu12 = { version = "^12.1.105", source = "torch_cu121" }
nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu12 = { version = "^12.1.105", source = "torch_cu121" }
nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu12 = { version = "^12.1.105", source = "torch_cu121" }
nvidia-cudnn-cu12 = { version = "^8.9.2.26", source = "torch_cu121" }
nvidia-cufft-cu12 = { version = "^11.0.2.54", source = "torch_cu121" }
nvidia-curand-cu12 = { version = "^10.3.2.106", source = "torch_cu121" }
nvidia-cusolver-cu12 = { version = "^11.4.5.107", source = "torch_cu121" }
nvidia-cusparse-cu12 = { version = "^12.1.0.106", source = "torch_cu121" }
nvidia-nccl-cu12 = { version = "^2.20.5", source = "torch_cu121" }
nvidia-nvtx-cu12 = { version = "^12.1.105", source = "torch_cu121" }
optimum = "^1.20.0"
tensorboard = "^2.17.0"
wheel = "^0.43.0"
pytorch-triton = { version = "^2.3.0", source = "torch_cu121" }

[tool.poetry.group.dev.dependencies]
black = "^24.4.2"
flake8 = "^7.0.0"
ipykernel = "^6.29.4"
ipywidgets = "^8.1.3"
seedir = "^0.4.2"
emoji = "^2.12.1"
nbformat = "^5.10.4"
nbclient = "^0.10.0"
nbconvert = "^7.16.4"


[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "torch_cu121"
url = "https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu121"
priority = "explicit"


[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "llama_cpp_python_cu121"
url = "https://abetlen.github.io/llama-cpp-python/whl/cu121"
priority = "explicit"


[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "torch_nightly_cu121"
url = "https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cu121/"
priority = "explicit"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"


Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/78022287/4601890  and https://pytorch.org/blog/what-every-user-should-know-about-mixed-precision-training-in-pytorch/
